# Custom list view delete row in android

Tags: android

I am using a custom list view in my application. In custom list view in all rows I have placed an image button. If I click that image button, I have to delete clicked button row in the custom list view. Can anybody tell me how to do this? The below coding is not working:

```
imgcross=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgcross);
 imgcross.setId(position);

 if(v.getId()==R.id.imgcross)
        {
            Log.d("image id is",Integer.toString(imgcross.getId()));
            myScheduleList.removeViewAt(imgcross.getId());
            Toast.makeText(MyScheduleDay0RequestedMeeting.this, "Cross Button is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

        }






 if (v.getId()==R.id.imgcross) 
{ //Integer index=(Integer)imgcross.getTag(); 
//Log.d("image id is",Integer.toString(index)); 
int index=imgcross.getId(); (imgcross.getId()); 
MyScheduleBean.listName.remove(index); 
MyScheduleBean.dateValue.remove(index); 
MyScheduleBean.dateValue.remove(index); 
CAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,MyScheduleBean.listName,MyScheduleBean.dateValue,MyScheduleBe­an.meeting,R.layout.myschedule_day0_requestedmeetingrow,to);
myScheduleList.setAdapter(CAdapter);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete the data from the underlying `Adapter`. Done properly, this will automatically update the `ListView`. Otherwise, also call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter`, and that will cause the `ListView` to update.

Comment: can you tell how to delete data from underlying adapter in click event even i tried with this

Comment: if(v.getId()==R.id.imgcross)
  {
   
   //Integer index=(Integer)imgcross.getTag();
   //Log.d("image id is",Integer.toString(index));
   int index=imgcross.getId();
      (imgcross.getId());
     MyScheduleBean.listName.remove(index);
     MyScheduleBean.dateValue.remove(index);
      MyScheduleBean.dateValue.remove(index);
    CAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,MyScheduleBean.listName,MyScheduleBean.dateValue,MyScheduleBean.meeting,R.layout.myschedule_day0_requestedmeetingrow,to);
   myScheduleList.setAdapter(CAdapter);         

   
  }

Comment: @mohan: I have no idea what any of that code does. To remove data from an `ArrayAdapter`, call `remove()` on the `ArrayAdapter`. To remove data from a `CursorAdapter`, modify the underlying data source (e.g., database) and `requery()` the `Cursor`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching too long for this answer - thank you very much.
After deleting the record from the database with:

```
DBRecordOperation.deleteRecord(dbRecord);
```

simply remove the record from the ListView with:

```
adapter.remove(dbRecord);
```

I'm doing this on a long click in the ListView.  Full code for onContextItemSelected is:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    DBRecord dbRecord = (DBRecord) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
    int dbRecordId = dbRecord.getId();

    DBRecordOperation.deleteRecord(dbRecord);
    adapter.remove(dbRecord);


    return true;

}
```